# DL4J. Ошибка при загрузке своего DataSet

Tags: java, intellij-idea, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Количество классов 96. При запуске файла, который создает наборы для тестирования и тренировки выдает ошибку:

> Reader output: 96 output classes, but array.size (1) is 58 (must be equal to 1 or numClasses = 96).

Пример взят c [FeaturizedPreSave](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/tree/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/transferlearning/vgg16)

- Deeplearning4j 1.0.0-alpha
- CUDA 8
- Java 8

> Exception in thread "AMDSI prefetch thread"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Cannot do conversion to one hot using batched reader: 96 output
>   classes, but array.size(1) is 58 (must be equal to 1 or numClasses =
>   96)   at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.iterator.AsyncMultiDataSetIterator$AsyncPrefetchThread.run(AsyncMultiDataSetIterator.java:374)
>   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot do
>   conversion to one hot using batched reader: 96 output classes, but
>   array.size(1) is 58 (must be equal to 1 or numClasses = 96)   at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.convertWritablesBatched(RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.java:351)
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.convertFeaturesOrLabels(RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.java:297)
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.nextMultiDataSet(RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.java:270)
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderMultiDataSetIterator.java:211)
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:367)
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:458)
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.datavec.RecordReaderDataSetIterator.next(RecordReaderDataSetIterator.java:85)
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.iterator.impl.MultiDataSetIteratorAdapter.next(MultiDataSetIteratorAdapter.java:62)
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.iterator.impl.MultiDataSetIteratorAdapter.next(MultiDataSetIteratorAdapter.java:13)
>     at
>   org.deeplearning4j.datasets.iterator.AsyncMultiDataSetIterator$AsyncPrefetchThread.run(AsyncMultiDataSetIterator.java:346)

И файлы:

- [EditLastLayerOthersFrozen](https://github.com/Piastres/example/blob/master/EditLastLayerOthersFrozen)
- [SymbolsDataSetIterator](https://github.com/Piastres/example/blob/master/SymbolsDataSetIterator)

Comment: приложите трейс ошибки и кусок кода, пожалуйста, нажав на [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/836227/edit)

Comment: @SeniorPomidor [Error](https://github.com/Piastres/example/blob/master/error_trace)
[Log](https://github.com/Piastres/example/blob/master/log_trace)